# How to invite people from my contact list via windows messager api or how to get explicit email addresses?

Tags: windows, winapi, hotmail, invitation

I tried to get emails for my website that users can invite their friends by email, but I have been receiving hashed emails. I found nothing and I decided to find the solution that help me to send emails via windows messenger api. Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the Messenger Connect API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/default.aspx

Comment: I have looked ! There was nothing ! But I saw this feature at some sites